# Planning scene (Get or Set)

Tags: ros, planning-scene, arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I don't understand why there are examples with this definition:

```
ros::ServiceClient get_planning_scene_client = nh.serviceClient<arm_navigation_msgs::GetPlanningScene>(SET_PLANNING_SCENE_DIFF_NAME);
```

GetPlanningScene with a SET_PLANNING_SCENE_DIFF_NAME?

While in other more advanced implementation, I have seen:

```
get_planning_scene = nh.serviceClient<arm_navigation_msgs::GetPlanningScene>(GET_PLANNING_SCENE_NAME);
set_planning_scene_diff = nh.serviceClient<arm_navigation_msgs::SetPlanningSceneDiff>(SET_PLANNING_SCENE_DIFF_NAME);
```

And if you want a snapshot of scene you use get, and if want change the scene you use set.

am I wrong? Could anybody explain to me in detail this functions?

Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49487/planning-scene-(get-or-set)/) by [Sanxano](https://answers.ros.org/users/1103/sanxano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2012-11-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The latter version you found is correct. Maybe the first one has the define pointing to the correct service name and the variable is just named badly or is doesn't work.

You understanding of the functionality seems also right.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0